# NO response launch SSH client while creating Ec2 instance

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, ssh, parse-server, cloud-storage

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEGOk.png)I am trying to create an ec2 instance on  Firefox browser not chrome and when i am  trying to connect  to  my instance on via a java ssh  client directly from my browser it is giving no response .I am trying hard for this.

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEGOk.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGvvX.png)

Comment: Are you correctly specifying the identity file (`.pem` file) AWS gives you?

Comment: yes,.... ofcourse

Comment: and what about the user? like when I login with `ssh` tool on my ubuntu I run it like, `ssh -i .ssh/id_aws.pem <user>@<aws-dns>` where <user> depends on the image you are using and <aws-dns> is the url to your instance that you can find in the console

Comment: it is for the first time i am creating an instance. And when I am trying to connect via java SSH client there is no response after clicking on Launch SSH client button

Comment: Could you please Edit your question and show us the configuration of the Security group associated with your instance. Also, are you receiving any error messages?

Comment: no i am not getting any error message

Comment: @JohnRotenstein how exactly u want me  to get it edited ..and  security group is parse server certified by bitnami

Comment: You can edit your question at any time by clicking the **Edit** link. The Security Group is defined within Amazon EC2 and should be associated with your EC2 instance. It defines what inbound traffic is permitted to access your instance. See: [Amazon EC2 Security Groups for Linux Instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html#vpc-security-groups)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein  hello sir... I have added the images within the question. can u please once check it

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEGOk.png these are the default security group     https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGvvX.png  and this is where i am getting problem

Comment: Sorry, but we need to see the contents of the **Inbound** tab for the security group. To work correctly, it will need an entry permitted access on Port 22 (SSH).

Answer (score 2):

The Run SSH client on browser is not reliable.

You should download a standalone SSH client.

If It's absolutely required for you to run it on the browser, check:

- Your browser's support for NPAPI and Java
- Find the setting and enable these options
- Re-install Java
- Switch to another browser ( Safari , Opera )

Anyways, If you are using Windows, you should use [Putty](https://www.putty.org/) to SSH to your EC2